# example of authentication-required swagger-ui-express APIs documentation

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-ui

**TL;DR**

Is there a complete example how to setup swagger-ui-express with basic authentication to restrict access to API documentation from general public ?

---

As we can learn many things from the [Swagger](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/) and [Swagger-UI-express](https://github.com/scottie1984/swagger-ui-express/) module documentation, from the issues on github related to the [authentication for swagger-ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20basicAuth) and also question raised on swagger-ui-express [github](https://github.com/scottie1984/swagger-ui-express/issues/112) as well. But there is no definitive explanation of how to setup, for example, minimal basic authentication with password and username to allow viewing the APIs only for authenticated users. I would like to align on that here.

Parts of what's required:

- the same Expressjs app has to own additional interceptor for the requests passed to `swaggerUi.serve` function
- openapi YAML file (from which we take the description of all endpoints etc.) needs to have basicAuth schema defined:

```yaml
security:
  - basicAuth: []

components:
  securitySchemes:
    basicAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: basic
```

- The swagger documentation loaded from openapi yaml doc is passed to the swagger-ui-express [setup](https://github.com/scottie1984/swagger-ui-express/blob/master/index.js#L180) function later passed as an [express middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

What we already have is:

```js
const swaggerUiExpress = require("swagger-ui-express")

app.use("/api-documentation", swaggerUiExpress.serve, swaggerUiExpress.setup("<path to swagger yaml file>"))
```

And what's missing is the middleware which is checking the authentication for the user. Is this logic correct? Seems to me overcomplicated if I can use just a simple auth with some token unknown to the most visitors.